# Chat server socket

Tags: c, sockets, chat

I am trying to create a threaded chat server in C, but cant figure out how to not echo the message back to the user. I want to be able to connect two or more clients and have the chat to each other through my server.

Where am I going wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<stdlib.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
#include<errno.h>

void *connectionHandler(void * soc_desc);

typedef struct { 
    int reader;
    int writer;
}args;

int main(int arc, char* argv[]){

    int *new_socket;
    int socFD;
    int client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    args t1args, t2args;
    int listenFd;
    //socklen_t clientSize= size(struct sockaddr_in);
    int c;
    int acceptFD;
    int client_sockets[2];

    socFD=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    puts("Socket created");

    bzero((char*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

    serveraddr.sin_family= AF_INET;

    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

    serveraddr.sin_port= htons(2000);

    bind(socFD, (struct sockaddr*) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

    puts("bind done");

    listen(socFD, 3);

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c= sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while((client_sock=accept(socFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr,(socklen_t *)&c)))
    {

        printf("%d", client_sock);
        puts("IN WHILE LOOP");

        pthread_t t1;
        new_socket= malloc(1);
        *new_socket=client_sock;

        if(pthread_create(&t1, NULL, connectionHandler, (void *)new_socket)<0){
                perror("Could not create thread");
                return -1;
        }
    }

    if(client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return -1;
    }

        return 0;
}

void *connectionHandler(void * soc_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
//      args *temp= (args*)soc_desc; 
        int sock= *(int*)soc_desc;
        int read_size;
        char *message , client_message[2000];
        char buff[80];
/*
        while(1){
             bzero(buff,sizeof(buff));
             recv(temp->reader,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
             send(temp->writer,buff,sizeof(buff),0);

        }*/
    //Receive a message from client
        while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) >0 )
        {
            //Send the message back to client
            write(sock, client_message ,strlen(client_message));
        }

        if(read_size == 0)
        {
            puts("Client disconnected");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else if(read_size == -1)
        {
            perror("recv failed");
        }

        //Free the socket pointer
        free(soc_desc);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't assume nul-terminated buffers. 2) dont use strlen() 3) use the return value from read() and write() instead. 4) that's all.

Comment: As I understand, before line `write(sock, client_message ,strlen(client_message));` you want to get message from other thread[s]?

Comment: No, I have multiple people connecting to this server and I want to pass the message along to each client, but not the sending client. I'm stuck on figuring out how to do this. I think I can do it with pthreads, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: "*I want to pass the message along to each client*" then read about linux IPC. In your case it could be a message queue or even one cycle buffer in shared memory: when one of threads gets message, it stores its contents somewhere and send some kind of signal to other threads, they read message and send it to their own clients. Also read about non-blocking sockets, or you'll need do another thing: threads would be only readers, and main process will store all descriptors of opened sockets and write messages to them on signal of any thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html

I did socket programming abt 3 yrs ago with C, this was what i followed. Helped me a lot.